# What id do I use for an OpenAI Assistant created with the GPT Builder UI

Tags: openai-api

I've created a custom GPT using the OpenAI web interface (https://chat.openai.com/gpts/editor)

Once created, I want to access that GPT via the Assistants API (https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/assistants/getAssistant)

The API example is `GET https://api.openai.com/v1/assistants/{assistant_id}`

When I try to use the id from the URL of the GPT, eg 'abcdefg' from https://chat.openai.com/gpts/editor/abcdefg, the API returns "No assistant found with id 'abcdefg'".

Is it possible to access web-interface created GPTs with the Assistants API? If so, how do I determine the `assistant_id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though, The GPTs and Assistant API focus on the same goal, it seems like they're two different things.

So, you cannot access the GPTs created with the web interface via the Assistance API.

Comment: However, you can transform your custom GPT into an assistant quite easily.

Comment: Yes. I agree :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the playground here: https://platform.openai.com/playground

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.